# Storing an array in a hash

Tags: perl

So, this doesn't work, and I have no idea why. I've tried every possible variation. But nothing works. I'm ready to take a chainsaw to my server, but hopefully you can prevent that:

```
sub getQuestMarkers {
  #database stuff
  ...
  my %package;
  while(my ($key, $lat, $lng) = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    $package{$key} = ($lat,$lng);
  }

  ...
  return %package;
}

my %markers = getQuestMarkers();
while(my( $key, $value) = each %markers) {
  print "$key: @value - $value[0] $value[1]\n";
}
```

Comment: [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator): "Binary `,` is the comma operator. In scalar context it evaluates its left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right argument and returns that value. This is just like C's comma operator."

Comment: Always start with `use strict; use warnings;`. That would have told you that `@value` doesn't exist (it wasn't declared anywhere).

Answer (score 3):

Use brackets `[ ]` to create an array reference, not parens `( )`;

As written, your code throws away the first value `$lat`.  Write it like this instead:

```
$package{$key} = [$lat,$lng];
```

You can pull out the values like this:

```
my ($lat,$lng) = @{ $package{$key} };
```

In your code, you could print out the values by dereferencing them:

```
print "$key: " . $value->[0] . " " . $value->[1] . "\n";
```

Have a look at [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been frustrating me for days.